# Script for Mac Mail Subject Line

Tags: macos, email

I send out shipment notices using Mac Mail to my customers, I have a signature template built, but I always have to put the words Your Order Has Shipped in my subject line.

Is there a script that I can run so that when I choose my signature from the Mac dropdown, it not only puts all the information in my signature but also puts the words Your Order Has Shipped in my Subject Line?

If this is doable, please give me user friendly instructions.  Thank you so much if anyone can help me.  This has bothered me for months, it's just one more step that would be wonderful if I could eliminate having to put this in manually.

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/387733/automate-subject-in-apples-mail-app

Answer (score 0):

Rather than clicking "Compose," you could create a new e-mail message from a link which specifies the subject.

The HTML code would be the following:

`<a href="mailto:?subject=Your Order Has Shipped">link</a>`

However, you should be able to create a `mailto` link within a Mac Mail compose window to save for later.

Comment: Thanks for helping me so quickly, Steven.  My signature has embedded images, I hoped I could just write a script so that I didn't have to build a .html email.  I also have other signatures and was hoping to modify the script to put different information in the subject line.  I hope this is doable, it will be pretty involved if I have to make .html signatures for every signature that I use.  Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you create a template.  Just keep a `mailto` link for composing a new "Your Order Has Shipped" with the subject line... rather than clicking Compose.